# How can I get next page javascript button using python

Tags: javascript, python

I'm using Python to get the next page referred with the following HTML code:

```
<td xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
class="rich-datascr-button"
onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'next'});">
<br _moz_dirty="" type="_moz"/></td>
```

I've been trying different options, but none worked.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: I would check the http headers that are requested when you click `next` link in browser. Somehow try to generate that URL from the data in current page & send the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

I've been traying Selenium, splinter from Brouser and Mechanize. I have learnt that Mechanize is not the way.

lately I have been trying  something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0


# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# go to the google home page
driver.get(url)


element =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(.,'???')]")
print element
```

The part of the table from the page I try to get is the one signaled by

```
<td class=" rich-datascr-button" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'next'});"></td>
```

and the table in the page looks like:

```
<div class="rich-datascr " id="tpForm:scroll2" style=" " align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="rich-dtascroller-table " id="tpForm:scroll2_table" style="text-align:center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="rich-datascr-button-dsbld rich-datascr-button">&#171;&#171;</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-button-dsbld rich-datascr-button">&#171;</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-button-dsbld rich-datascr-button"></td>
<td class="rich-datascr-act ">1</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '2'});">2</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '3'});">3</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '4'});">4</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '5'});">5</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '6'});">6</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '7'});">7</td>
<td class="rich-datascr-inact " onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '8'});">8</td>
<td class=" rich-datascr-button" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'next'});"></td>
<td class=" rich-datascr-button" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'fastforward'});">&#187;</td>
<td class=" rich-datascr-button" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': 'last'});">Last</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">new Richfaces.Datascroller('tpForm:scroll2', function(event){A4J.AJAX.Submit('tpForm',event,{'ignoreDupResponses':true,'implicitEventsQueue':'tpForm:scroll2','similarityGroupingId':'tpForm:scroll2','parameters':{'tpForm:scroll2':event.memo.page,'ajaxSingle':'tpForm:scroll2'} } ); return false;});</script>
</div>
```

What I wolud like is to obtain the next part of the table by code in Python to acces to the list of references of each part. I can figure out at thislast point using urlparse, BeautifulSoup and urllib2. My problem is get net page in the table.

Comment: This belongs to the question, not as a separate answer.